# Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements with prolog

Tags: prolog

The original problem was to come up with a way to get the following

```
remove([a,a,a,b,q,q,q,q,e,e,e]),X)
X = [a,b,q,e]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this problem by one iteration along the list. At any point in the list we check the current element and the next element, if they are the same then we ignore the current element, else if they are different we take the current element.

```
rm_dup([], []).
rm_dup([X], [X]).
rm_dup([X1, X2 | Xs], [X1 | Ys]) :-
    dif(X1, X2), rm_dup([X2|Xs], Ys).
rm_dup([X, X | Xs], Ys) :-
    rm_dup([X | Xs], Ys).
```

The first and second clauses are base clauses in which there are no duplicate elements. The third and fourth clauses are recursive rules.

In third clause we state that if the input list has two values `X1` and `X2` and they are different `dif(X1, X2)`, then keep the current value.

In fourth clause if we have same consecutive values then we ignore the current value.

The third and fourth clauses are mutually exclusive and hence to make the predicate deterministic it is better to combine them as follows

```
rm_dup([X], [X]) :- !.
rm_dup([X1, X2 | Xs], Ys) :-
    dif(X1, X2) -> (rm_dup([X2 | Xs], Ys1), Ys = [X1 | Ys1]);
    rm_dup([X2 | Xs], Ys).
```

Even better is to just use equality as a condition and flip the *then* and *else* clauses.

```
rm_dup([X], [X]) :- !.
rm_dup([X1, X2 | Xs], Ys) :-
    X1 = X2 ->  rm_dup([X2 | Xs], Ys);
    rm_dup([X2 | Xs], Ys1), Ys = [X1 | Ys1].
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Don't you want to post a solution that is also determinate with current Prologs?

Comment: Your two improvements are no longer equivalent to your original correct but just a bit inefficient solution.

Comment: @false : You mean to cut rather than combine the two clauses?

Comment: Both the visible cut as well as the cut hidden in the if-then-else ruin the clean semantics of your original correct program.

Comment: @false: I get it that you did not mean this when you said to make a `solution that is also determinate with current Prologs`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @rajashekar: if you use `rm_dup([X, Y], R)`, it should provide two answers `[X]` and `[X,Y]` with a `dif(X, Y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda long, but this solved it.

```
delete(_,[],[]).
delete(X,[X|T],R):- delete(X,T,R).
delete(X,[H|T],[H|R]) :- delete(X,T,R).

remove([],[]).
remove([H|T], [H|R]) :- 
    member(H,T),!,
    delete(H,T,R1),
    remove(R1,R).

remove([H|T],[H|R]):-
    remove(T,R).
```

Comment: `remove([a,b,a],Xs).` gives two answers, but only one is correct..

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use sort.

**First:** In the base class if the List are empty stop.

**Second:** In the second predicate, take the list and sort it. Display the answer in K.

```
remove_extras([],[]).
remove_extras([H|T],K):-
    sort([H|T], K).

?-remove_extras([a,a,a,b,q,q,q,q,e,e,e],X).
X = [a, b, e, q]

?-remove_extras([1,3,2,5,1,6,1,2,7],X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

If you don't want to use sort, you can use the following predicates:
Remove duplicates checks for elements existing more than once and keeps them in the list.

**First:** The base case says that if the lists are empty stop.

**Second:** The second predicate checks if an element  exist in the remaining list (member) then don't add it to the final list.

**Third:** The third predicate says, if the element is in not the remaining list then add it to the final list.

```
remove_duplicates([],[]).
remove_duplicates([H | T], List) :-    
     member(H, T),
     remove_duplicates( T, List).

remove_duplicates([H | T], [H|T1]) :- 
     \+ member(H, T),
      remove_duplicates( T, T1).
```

Comment: `remove_extras([a,X],[a]).` fails, yet its specialization `X = a, remove_extras([a,X],[a]).` succeeds correctly.

Comment: I don't think the asker is going to use the test case you have mentioned. Got to keep it simple.

Comment: Not even `remove_extras([b,a],[b,a])` which fails as well?

Comment: It's still not what the asker asked.