# Remove repeating elements in list, Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was wondering if there's any way to remove repeating elements in prolog only if they're nearby eachother.

At the moment I could only do this:

Input:

```
([z,z,z,z,z,x,x,x,c,c,c,z,z,z], R)
```

And i get output:

```
R = [x,c,z].
```

But i wanna see output like this:

```
R = [z,x,c,z].
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How did you *implement* the predicate? `(L, R)` does not remove elements from a list.

Comment: how do you define nearby? Next to each other?

Comment: There is a smiliar question and  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046664/8080648) already asked a few days ago.

Comment: yes, nearby is next to each other.
I don't need to delete them every time I see them
I wanna do like that:
Input:
[z,z,z,x,x,x,z,z,z,x,x,x,z,z,z]
Output:
[z,x,z,x,z]

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially *run length encoding*, where you might compress `[a,a,a,b,c,c,c,c,c]` to `[a:3,b,c:5]` or a similar representation. Except that we don't care about the length of the run (or do we?)

```
collapse([],[]).
collapse([X|Xs], Ys ) :- collapse(X,Xs,Ys).

collapse( X , []     , [X]    ) .
collapse( Y , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- Y \= X , collapse(X,Xs,Ys) .
collapse( Y , [X|Xs] , Ys     ) :- Y  = X , collapse(Y,Xs,Ys) .
```

[computation of run length is left as an exercise for the reader].

Answer (score 0):

You can each time look if the next element can be unified with the current element. If that is the case we skip the element, otherwise we start a new "group", so:

```
uniqs([], []).
uniqs([H|T], R) :-
    uniqs(T, H, R).

uniqs([], X, [X]).
uniqs([X|T], X, R) :-
    uniqs(T, X, R).
uniqs([Y|T], X, [X|R]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    uniqs(T, Y, R).
```

For the given sample input, this gives us:

```
?- uniqs([z,z,z,z,z,x,x,x,c,c,c,z,z,z], R).
R = [z, x, c, z] ;
false.
```